# Terraform: SSH authentication failed (user@:22): ssh: handshake failed

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I wrote some Terraform code to create a new VM and want to execute a command on it via `remote-exec` but it throws an SSH connection error:

```
Error: timeout - last error: SSH authentication failed (admin@:22): ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain.
```

My Terraform code:

```
# Create a resource group if it doesn’t exist
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "${var.deployment}-mp-rg"
  location = "${var.azure_environment}"

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.deployment}"
  }
}

# Create virtual network
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "${var.deployment}-mp-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = "${var.azure_environment}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.deployment}"
  }
}

# Create subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = "${var.deployment}-mp-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  virtual_network_name = "${azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name}"
  address_prefix       = "10.0.1.0/24"
}

# Create public IPs
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "publicip" {
  name                = "${var.deployment}-mp-publicip"
  location            = "${var.azure_environment}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.deployment}"
  }
}

# Create Network Security Group and rule
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = "${var.deployment}-mp-nsg"
  location            = "${var.azure_environment}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"

  security_rule {
    name                       = "SSH"
    priority                   = 1001
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "22"
    source_address_prefix      = "*"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.deployment}"
  }
}

# Create network interface
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "nic" {
  name                      = "${var.deployment}-mp-nic"
  location                  = "${var.azure_environment}"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "${var.deployment}-mp-nicconfiguration"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.subnet.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${azurerm_public_ip.publicip.id}"
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.deployment}"
  }
}

# Generate random text for a unique storage account name
resource "random_id" "randomId" {
  keepers = {
    # Generate a new ID only when a new resource group is defined
    resource_group = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  }

  byte_length = 8
}

# Create storage account for boot diagnostics
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storageaccount" {
  name                     = "diag${random_id.randomId.hex}"
  resource_group_name      = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  location                 = "${var.azure_environment}"
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.deployment}"
  }
}

# Create virtual machine
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                  = "${var.deployment}-mp-vm"
  location              = "${var.azure_environment}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.nic.id}"]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "${var.deployment}-mp-disk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
  }

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${var.deployment}-mp-ansible"
    admin_username = "${var.ansible_user}"
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true
    ssh_keys {
      path     = "/home/${var.ansible_user}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
      key_data = "${var.public_key}"
    }
  }

  boot_diagnostics {
    enabled     = "true"
    storage_uri = "${azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount.primary_blob_endpoint}"
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "${var.deployment}"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "ssh_connection" {

  connection {
    host        = "${azurerm_public_ip.publicip.ip_address}"
    type        = "ssh"
    private_key = "${file(var.private_key)}"
    port        = 22
    user        = "${var.ansible_user}"
    agent       = false
    timeout     = "1m"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = ["sudo apt-get -qq install python"]
  }
}
```

I have tried to SSH into the new VM manually with `admin@xx.xx.xx.xx:22` and it works. Looking at the error message I then output the parameter `${azurerm_public_ip.publicip.ip_address}` but it is `null` so I think that this is the reason why the SSH authentication failed but I don't know the reason. If I want to SSH the server via Terraform script, how can I modify the code?

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to change the `private_key` with the value `var.private_key`, without the file function. Or do not use the variable, just use the file function to input the file context.

Comment: @CharlesXu Yep, I have changed this part, but the main thing is that the public ip cannot get only after been attached to the data module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that Terraform has built a dependency graph that tells it that the only dependency for the `null_resource.ssh_connection` is the `azurerm_public_ip.publicip` resource and so it's starting to try to connect before the instance has been created.

This in itself isn't a massive issues as the provisioner would normally attempt to retry in case SSH isn't yet available but the connection details are being determined as soon as the null resource starts. And with the `azurerm_public_ip` set to an [`allocation_method`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/public_ip.html#allocation_method) of `Dynamic` it won't get its IP address until after it has been attached to a resource:

> Note Dynamic Public IP Addresses aren't allocated until they're assigned to a resource (such as a Virtual Machine or a Load Balancer) by design within Azure - more information is available below.

There's a few different ways you can solve this. You could make the `null_resource` [depend](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#resource-dependencies) on the `azurerm_virtual_machine.vm` resource via interpolation or via [`depends_on`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#depends_on-explicit-resource-dependencies):

```
resource "null_resource" "ssh_connection" {

  connection {
    host        = "${azurerm_public_ip.publicip.ip_address}"
    type        = "ssh"
    private_key = "${file(var.private_key)}"
    port        = 22
    user        = "${var.ansible_user}"
    agent       = false
    timeout     = "1m"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "echo ${azurerm_virtual_machine.vm.id}",
      "sudo apt-get -qq install python",
    ]
  }
}
```

or

```
resource "null_resource" "ssh_connection" {
  depends_on = ["azurerm_virtual_machine.vm"]

  connection {
    host        = "${azurerm_public_ip.publicip.ip_address}"
    type        = "ssh"
    private_key = "${file(var.private_key)}"
    port        = 22
    user        = "${var.ansible_user}"
    agent       = false
    timeout     = "1m"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = ["sudo apt-get -qq install python"]
  }
}
```

A better approach here would to be to run the provisioner as part of the `azurerm_virtual_machine.vm` resource instead of a `null_resource`. The normal reasons to use a `null_resource` to launch a provisioner are when you need to wait until after something else has happened to a resource such as attaching a disk or if there's [not an appropriate resource to attach it to](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) but this doesn't really apply here. So instead of your existing `null_resource` you'd move the provisioner into the `azurerm_virtual_machine.vm` resource:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  # ...

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      host        = "${azurerm_public_ip.publicip.ip_address}"
      type        = "ssh"
      private_key = "${file(var.private_key)}"
      port        = 22
      user        = "${var.ansible_user}"
      agent       = false
      timeout     = "1m"
    }

    inline = ["sudo apt-get -qq install python"]
  }
}
```

For many resources this also allows you to refer to the outputs of the resource you are provisioning by using the [`self` keyword](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#attributes-of-your-own-resource). Unfortunately the `azurerm_virtual_machine` resource doesn't seem to easily expose the IP address of the VM due to this being set by the `network_interface_ids`.

Comment: I have tried the upper 3 ways, but not working for all of them...Still trying to find out the real issue here

Comment: Know the reason, added a data module for `azurerm_public_ip`, 

the example from terraform: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/public_ip.html